# TYPO3 Gridelements Content Element - Column switches to "INVALID VALUE ("-2")"

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.7.x, tx-gridelements

Sometimes I face the problem, that in a Content Element the Column switches from "Grid Container" to `INVALID VALUE ("-2")` - See the below. The corresponding element is nested 5 times.

[image]

This behavior happens very rarely and at random. There are some answers to this issue, but they are all outdated.

The issue was manually fixed, nevertheless, it occurs again after various timespans.

Anyone who also faced this problem and has an answer to that?

**TYPO3: 8.7.13

Gridelements: 8.2.3**

Answer (score 0):

You should try latest 8-0 branch of the Git-Repository, since the issue is most likely connected to: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85511